# Pipeline for Angular Application

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, pipeline

I am trying to set up CICD for angular application and as the first step trying to install the npm as build process and i facing issue at this step.

Log:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ npm install
npm WARN deprecated @types/moment@2.13.0: This is a stub types definition for Moment (https://github.com/moment/moment). Moment provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/moment installed!
npm WARN deprecated datauri@1.1.0: Datauri 2.0 released. See more in https://github.com/data-uri/datauri/releases/tag/v2.0.0
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update! 
npm WARN deprecated mimer@0.3.2: Mimer 1.0 released. See more in https://github.com/data-uri/mimer/releases/tag/v1.0.0
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @pnc-wbb/wbb-ui-styles@2.4.6

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jnkcbr/.npm/_logs/2019-04-24T14_47_44_277Z-debug.log
[Pipeline] }
```

Can someone help me with that this error means and what i should do to correct it.

Thanks

Comment: It means your package.json references (directly or indirectly) a pakage named @pnc-wbb/wbb-ui-styles, with version 2.4.6, which doesn't exist in the npm registry. https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=%40pnc-wbb%2Fwbb-ui-styles

Comment: Thank youso much, i will check the same.